# Unable to intercept App Transport Policy errors in UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have a iOS application in Swift where I show a `UIWebView` where I show content received from a WebService (that I have no control over). Some of these URLs are unsafe HTTP addresses, so I implemented a small mechanism to open the URL in Safari when I receive a App Transport Policy errors:

```
// MARK: UIWebViewDelegate
func webView(webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError?) {
    guard let error = error else { return }
    NSLog("Received error: \(error)")
    if error.domain == NSURLErrorDomain && error.code == NSURLErrorAppTransportSecurityRequiresSecureConnection {
        NSLog("App transport policy error")
        // Open in safari
        //UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }
}
```

So far works as expected, when I try to open (or navigate to) an unsafe URL, a `NSURLErrorAppTransportSecurityRequiresSecureConnection` error is intercepted, then I close the webview and open Safari.

However, when the HTML uses some unsafe resources, the page doesn't load but I get no errors. For example, the following HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css"></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><img src="http://i.imgur.com/nwo13SM.png" style="width:100%"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Drops an error message on the command line:

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

But the webview delegate method is not being called, so I end up with a page full of errors instead of opening in Safari.

Is there any way to detect / intercept these unsafe content errors in order to open the URL in Safari?

NOTE: I don't want to load unsafe content. I want to detect it and redirect it to Safari.

Comment: What if you parsed the web page to check for `http://` content before trying to load it in your `UIWebView`?

Comment: That could work in some scenarios, but thinking about HTML comments, XML schemas and other exceptions gives me chills :(

Comment: That seems like an interesting idea. A mini browser that only works for "safe" connections and "recommends" Safari for the rest. Just an idea, but have you tried it with WKWebView to see whether it perhaps behaves differently?

Comment: @Gero Now that iOS 10 is on the way, I could drop iOS 7 compatibility and stick to `WKWebView`. I'll check how it works and post back results. Thanks